# How can I parse and optimize a mathematical expression from a string?

Tags: java, math

Is there any way to parse a math equation from a String and then optimize it?

For example, I have an equation like "`(1*a) + (2*a) + (3*a) = b`" and I want to parse it as a Function while automatically being reduced to this `(1+2+3)*a = b`

Comment: *Is there any way to parse a math equation from a String and then optimize it?*  Yes, there certainly is.  But your search engine is a better place to ask this question.  Or you could have a look at the myriad questions and answers on the topic on this very site.

Comment: Can you guarantee that equations will have a certain format, in terms of allowed operators and unknowns? For example, if there is only 1 level of subexpressions on each side, and no nested parenthesis, things are much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the open source Java [Symja library](https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library) you can solve your problem like this:

```
package org.matheclipse.core.examples;

import org.matheclipse.core.eval.ExprEvaluator;
import org.matheclipse.core.interfaces.IExpr;
import org.matheclipse.parser.client.SyntaxError;
import org.matheclipse.parser.client.math.MathException;

public class SimplifySO62754337 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ExprEvaluator util = new ExprEvaluator();
            IExpr result = util.eval("(1*a) + (2*a) + (3*a) == b");
            // print: 6*a==b
            System.out.println(result.toString());
        } catch (SyntaxError e) {
            // catch Symja parser errors here
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (MathException me) {
            // catch Symja math errors here
            System.out.println(me.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Those seem like two questions. First, how to get text into an in-memory representation of a mathematical expression (an equation can be seen as two expressions that are declared to be equal). Then, how to simplify that expression.

The first part is frequently taught in introductory compiler courses (most programming languages can parse expressions, although formats differ). Have a look at, say, [AntLR](https://github.com/antlr), a parser generator for Java. You specify a grammar (how your expressions should be written, what operators you want to include, precedence, ...); and it generates Java code to convert text into in-memory expressions.

The second part, simplification, is harder. AFAIK, there are no general toolkits to do that, because it depends on your operators: do they have side-effects? are they commutative, associative?. Optimizers like to play it safe, because unless an expression is identical to the "optimized" version in *all* circumstances, the optimization could break it for those exceptions.

In the specific case of math, there are several symbolic-manipulation programs which I have seen do similar simplifications to the one you describe. For example, typing it into wolfram alpha.

That said, adding a few rules should be easy once you have an in-memory tree. For example,

- if you compute the same thing many times, compute it once
- added multiples of the same unknown can be simplified into a single multiple of that unknown (your example)
- multiplying by 1 or adding zero can be elided; multiplying by zero yields zero and need not be calculated
- ...